# How to filter EC2 instances in prometheus.yml?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, prometheus

I am trying to filter EC2 instances in `prometheus.yml`. Suppose that the following is part of the yml file. How can I use regex in the values to return instance that starts with, lets say, `prod` or `qa` or other labels? Is this possible without configuring `relabeling`?

```
  ec2_sd_configs:
- region: us-east-1
  access_key: access
  secret_key: mysecret
  profile: profile
  filters:
    - name: tag:Name
      values:
        - prod.*
        - qa.*
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that Prometheus does not support regex in filtering API right now but it would be a nice feature if they can add it in future releases. What can be done in this situation is that you can add a separate tag on EC2 instances so you can filter based on those tag. Filtering at early stage is extremely helpful if you have large number of instances. Otherwise, you'll get a huge list and you need to go through a drop/keep phase via relabeling which still keeps a long list in service discovery panel and make it difficult to read.

In the next step, you can use relabeling to replace the address of each discovered instance from private IP to public IP. As a final touch, you can replace the instance name with the tag name so, for example, all instances of QA are labeled as QA.

```yaml
     ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: value
        access_key: value
        secret_key: value
        port: value
        filters:
          - name: tag:Name
            values:
              - qa
              - prod
              - some other types
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_public_ip]
        replacement: '${1}:your port number'
        target_label: __address__
      - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Name]
        target_label: instance
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with AWS, but I believe its API does not support regular expressions in filtering API.

In general relabelling is the preferred way to do filtering. An example of how to achieve this would be (for consul, but that does not matter much): [Prometheus: how to drop a target based on Consul tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376937/prometheus-how-to-drop-a-target-based-on-consul-tags)
List of ec2 meta labels available is in prometheus docs at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#ec2_sd_config

I see that Prometheus docs recommend using filters over relabelling for efficiency reasons when you have potentially thousands of instances. Using separate tag (for example "Env") that has values of "qa", "prod" etc. so they can be matched exactly (without regex/wildcard) would be an elegant solution here I'd guess?

Comment: Yeah, I followed a somehow similar approach but filtering is not complete without relabeling. I posted a detailed answer in case someone need that in future. Thank you for your response.